# Is there a Cauchy sequence containing all the rationals in a bounded set?

Tags: metric-spaces

Is there a Cauchy sequence containing all the rationals in a bounded set with non-empty interior? More generally, let $X$ be a separable, complete metric space with countable dense subset $U$, and let $K$ be a bounded (or maybe compact?) subset of $X$ with non-empty interior. Does there exist a Cauchy sequence which contains all of the countably many points in $K \cap U$?

My motivation for this is that I'm currently trying to prove that quasisymmetric maps preserve completeness, and my proof depends on the sequences above not existing.

Comment: Could you be more precise with what you mean by “all the rationals in a bounded set”? If that bounded set is finite, then surely there’s no issue having a Cauchy sequence that contains these elements

Comment: The answer to the question that I **think** you’re trying to ask is no. In particular, for any Cauchy sequence, the set of elements in the sequence can have at most one limit point.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say also that the set has non-empty interior. And yes, of course you're correct, I'm forgetting basic properties of Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence that does not converge to $p$, there exist $\epsilon > 0$ and $N$ such that $d(x_n, p) > \epsilon$ for $n > N$.